# identifying the second instance

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a string like this:

```
[url=http://www.las-vegas.cc/weddings.php:1d5lzpq4]Las Vegas Wedding[/url:1d5lzpq4]
```

And i need to clean it to make it valid html, like this:

```
<a href="http://www.las-vegas.cc/weddings.php" target="blank">Las Vegas Wedding</a>
```

I thought of using a regex to do the dirty work and came up with:

```
/\[url=(.+(?:))\](.*)\[\/url:.*\]/Ui
```

But this is not working properly since my results are

```
1 - http://www.las-vegas.cc/weddings.php:1d5lzpq4
2 - Las Vegas Wedding
```

How should i modify my regex to remove the part after the `:`?
It is the 2nd instance of `:` in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
~\[url=([^]]+):[^]]*](.*?)\[/url:[^]]*]~is
```

Note that i didn't exclude the `:` from the first character class to deal with an eventual login/pass in the url and to be sure to find the last `:` using the backtracking. So

```
$result = preg_replace('~\[url=([^]]+):[^]]*](.*?)\[/url:[^]]*]~is', '<a href="$1">$2</a>', $text);
```

Details of the part: `([^]]+):[^]]*]`

`[^]]` is the character class that matches all characters except `]`.

`[^]]+` will match all characters until the closing `]` but the regex engine will go back (backtracking mechanism) until it find the `:` to make the pattern succeed.

Once done, `[^]]*` will match the last characters until the closing `]`

Comment: this works thank you. Now, time to break it into little pieces and find out exaclty how it works ::)